# 3 Errors while building apk with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a noob at Android programming, so I used Buildbox to make some kind of Android game...and when I was at the stage where I was supposed to import my game, 3 errors popped up in the problems section...I'm gonna just copy and paste them:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'

The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\BBDOC EXPORT\WallJump\android\libs\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar'
```

And the obvious one:

```
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
```

I'm gonna upload a screenshot too...
[Click here to see for yourself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8jSx.png)

If you guys need any more details just tell me.

Comment: The error says the theme used in the application as parent theme is not found. It might be because either you don't have that theme in your project, or it is not supported for the current sdk. And you should add your google-play-services_lib.jar in your workspace . You have to import this jar as a library in your project.

Comment: actually the errors are 4, you're using Eclipse